# Music.app on iOS: use a different language other than the system language?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, music.app

As explained in the title, I want to use Music.app in a different language other than the system language.

However, unlike many other apps, it doesn't offer such an option in settings.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do so by tweaking appropriate plist files. If so, how?

Comment: There is no way to tweak files in iOS, unless you a going to jail break the device.

Comment: @TomGewecke it seems possible to do it via iMazing. Just backup, edit and restore.

Comment: Why not put that as the answer then?

Comment: @TomGewecke I mean it is possible to tweak plist files using iMazing. In fact, such method actually works for Maps.app. However plist files of Music.app seems different from ordinary apps. I am still experimenting on Music.app.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no - there’s no published setting to make this edit for Apple’s app. That doesn’t mean it’s not possible, just that it’s unknown.

Applying pressure to Apple for this may or may not be effective, and hopefully someone can document this and make my answer wrong or in need of an edit to explain how.